# How do i fix a map api key?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have created a map API key but it's not working can you help me how can i resolve it thanks

Here is website link: https://earnest-participati.000webhostapp.com/

```js
"use strict";
var $placePicker = null,
    $modal = null,
    n=null,
    btnClass="btn btn-secondary btn-sm",
    placePickerMap = null,
    marker = false,
    service = null,
    geocoder = null,
    result = null;
$.fn.PlacePicker = function (t) {
    n = {
        key : null,
        title : null,
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 18,
        success: function () {}
    };
    var params = $.extend(n, t);
    $placePicker = this;
    $(this).wrap( "<div></div>" );
    $(this).closest("div").hover(function(){
        var left = $(this).offset().left+$(this).width() - 40;
        var top = $(this).offset().top+5;
        var btn = $('<div class="placePickerUIButton" title="Pick location from map" style="position:absolute;top: '+top+'px;left: '+left+'px;z-index: 1000;"><div class="'+params.btnClass+'"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></div></div>');
        $(this).append(btn);
        btn.click(function(){
            if($("body").find(".modal.placePicker").length==0){
                $("body").append('<div class="modal fade in placePicker" role="dialog"><style>.pac-container{ z-index: 10000; }</style><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 90%;"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Place Picker</h4><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button></div><div class="modal-body" style="padding: 0px;"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px;position: absolute;z-index: 1;background: #fff;width: 30%;margin-left: 20px;margin-top: 4px;box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)!important;"><div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 100%;"> <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right autocomplete" placeholder="Search here or pick a location on map" style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;" autocomplete="off"></div><div class="address_content" style="display: none"><div class="address" style="margin-top: 10px;display: block;padding: 9.5px;font-size: 13px;color: #333;background-color: #f5f5f5;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;max-height: 50vh;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll;text-align: left;"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="btn btn-sm btn-success placePickerSubmit" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Select</div></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div id="placePickerMap" style="height:calc( 80vh );width:100%"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
            }
            result = null;
            $modal = $(".placePicker");
            $modal.modal("show");
            $(".placePicker").find(".address").html("");
            $(".placePicker").find(".address_content").hide();
            $(".placePicker").find(".autocomplete").val("");
            placePickerMap = null
            marker = false;
            if (!(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object')) {
                $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+params.key+'&libraries=places', function() {
                    initPlacePickerMap(params)
                });
            } else{
                initPlacePickerMap(params)
            }
            if(params.title!=null){
                $modal.find(".modal-title").html(params.title);
            }
            $(".placePickerSubmit").click(function(){
                var place = $(".placePicker").find(".autocomplete");
                params.success(convertAddress(),place);
                $modal.modal("hide")
            });
            $modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $("body").find(".modal.placePicker").remove();
            })
        });
    },
    function(){
        $("body").find(".placePickerUIButton").remove();
    });


};
function initPlacePickerMap(params) {
    service = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(params.center.lat, params.center.lng);
        placePickerMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('placePickerMap'), {
            center: loc,
            zoom: params.zoom
        });
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(placePickerMap);
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete")[0]);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            if (typeof place.address_components !== 'undefined') {
                placePickerMap.panTo(place.geometry.location)
                if(marker === false){
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: place.geometry.location,
                        map: placePickerMap,
                        draggable: true
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event){
                        markerLocation();
                    });
                } else{
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                }
                markerLocation();
            }

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(placePickerMap, 'click', function(event) {
            var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
            if(marker === false){
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: clickedLocation,
                    map: placePickerMap,
                    draggable: true
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event){
                    markerLocation();
                });
            } else{
                marker.setPosition(clickedLocation);
            }
            markerLocation();
        });
    }, 1000);
}
function markerLocation(){
    var currentLocation = marker.getPosition();
    geocoder.geocode({'location': currentLocation}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
            result = results[0];
            var cont = "<h6 style='font-weight:600;font-size: 16px;padding-bottom: 10px;'>"+result.formatted_address+"</h6>";
            $(result.address_components).each(function(key,value){
                cont += "<b>"+value.types.join(', ')+"</b> : "+value.long_name+"<br>";
            });
            $(".address").html(cont);
            $(".address_content").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
function convertAddress(){
    var data=[];
    data["country"]="";
    data["administrative_area_level_2"]="";
    data["postal_code"]="";
    data["sublocality_level_1"]="";
    data["sublocality_level_2"]="";
    data["route"]="";
    data["locality"]="";
    data["formatted_address"] = result.formatted_address;
    $(result.address_components).each(function(i,address){
        $(address.types).each(function(j,type){
            if(type=="country"){
                data[type] = address.short_name;
            }else{
                data[type] = address.long_name;
            }
        });
    });
    return data;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="PlacePicker.png">

    <title>Google Place Picker For Bootstrap Example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="PlacePicker.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
      <img class="mb-4" src="PlacePicker.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Google Place Picker For Bootstrap Example</h1>
      <div class="jquery-script-ads" style="margin:30px auto"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Address</label>
      <input type="email" id="pickup_country" class="form-control" placeholder="Address"  autofocus>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pickup_country").PlacePicker({
            btnClass:"btn btn-xs btn-default",
            key:"AIzaSyCi5tx8le0PuE2P2vJnIdclkVeUL33WPjg",
            center: {lat: 17.6868, lng: 83.2185},
            success:function(data,address){
                //data contains address elements and
                //address conatins you searched text
                //Your logic here
                $("#pickup_country").val(data.formatted_address);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
.form-signin {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 630px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the setting of the API key please check and let me know. If you can help me let me know. I'm waitunf for your response thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtEQZ.png)

Comment: Please don't share your private keys !